# Twig loop.first not working

Tags: twig

I have the following :

```
{% for field in fields -%}
  <div class="item{% if loop.first %} active{% endif %}">
    {{ field.content }}
  </div>
{%- endfor %}
```

but it's adding the active class to every field wrapper, rather than just the first which is my intention.

Comment: Code is just [fine](https://twigfiddle.com/rsghhe), sure you aren't using an (old) cached version? Clear the cache or enable `auto_reload`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Darkbee.  User malfunction here.  The code was in a nested template file ( Drupal ) and the loop I thought I was iterating through was actually in a higher level template file.